# Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста выбивает ошибку: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'BatteryLevel.text'

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

```
public static float GetBatteryLevel()
{


    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
    {
        try
        {
            using (AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
            {
                if (null != unityPlayer)
                {
                    using (AndroidJavaObject currActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
                    {
                        if (null != currActivity)
                        {
                            using (AndroidJavaObject intentFilter = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.IntentFilter", new object[]{ "android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" }))
                            {
                                using (AndroidJavaObject batteryIntent = currActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("registerReceiver", new object[]{null,intentFilter}))
                                {
                                    int level = batteryIntent.Call<int>("getIntExtra", new object[]{"level",-1});
                                    int scale = batteryIntent.Call<int>("getIntExtra", new object[]{"scale",-1});

                                    // Error checking that probably isn't needed but I added just in case.
                                    if (level == -1 || scale == -1)
                                    {
                                        return 50f;
                                    }
                                    return ((float)level / (float)scale) * 100.0f;

                                    BatteryLevel.text.GetComponent<Text>().text = level;
                                }
                           
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
         
        }
    }
 
    return 100;

}
```

}

Comment: Если `BatteryLevel` у вас это GameObject, то у вас синтаксическая ошибка, замените `BatteryLevel.text.GetComponent<Text>()`на `BatteryLevel.GetComponent<Text>()` в конце.

Comment: Мне нужно выводить количество оставшегося заряда батареи на экран(я попробовал много методов, но так и не нашел способа вывода не процентами, а изображением) проблема исчезла, так как я убрал static в функции, спасибо Вам большое за помощь, но к сожалению я так и не добился своего - так и не удалось добиться показа оставшегося заряда...(

Comment: Что такое вывод заряда изображением?

Comment: видел на смартфоне у тебя такой прямоугольник вверху, и в нем показывается сколько осталось зарядки? а когда у тебя например меньше чем 15% осталось - он окрашивается в красный